# Can`t draw borders on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am trying to draw borders for certain countries on a google map using some geojson data.
I've added the entire geojson in an array at the beginning of the js file.
The problem I encounter is that for certain countries the borders aren't drawn at all. For ex: Canada, USA, Russia, France, Australia etc.
I've tried modifiing so that I have only polygons or a smaller no. of geolocations but the problem still persists.
Here is the repo with the html and js for the map: [git repo](https://github.com/lau32/IP)
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your MultiPolygon code isn't working correctly.  Canada is only displaying Prince Edward Island.

Comment: By any chance are all the countries that aren't working those where the type is MultiPolygon not Polygon?  Suggest you investigate lines 227-251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, your problem is with your multi-dimensional arrays of coordinates (surprise surprise).  Sweden for instance is fine, Canada isn't, even though both are the MultiPolygon type.  See if you can spot the difference here (code truncated for brevity):

Canada:

```
 "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [-63.6645, 46.55001],
                            ...
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            [-61.806305, 49.10506],
                            ...
                        ]
                    ],
```

Sweden:

```
"coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [22.183173, 65.723741],
                            ...
                        ],
                        [
                            [17.061767, 57.385783],
                            ...
                        ],
```

The Canadian one (and presumably all the others that aren't working) should instead be structured like:

```
 "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [-63.6645, 46.55001],
                            ...
                        ],
                        [
                            [-61.806305, 49.10506],
                            ...
                        ]
```

I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/duncancumming/IP/commit/a12abe053c3e64db766dbc3f4fc4f89a81dacd88?diff=unified) fixing Canada. You can sort the other countries yourself!